# rotate object onclick

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation

So i have the code that is supposed to add when clicked "+10" button 10degree rotation to object, when clicked "+30" button 30degree rotation to the object, the 90degree position to be max available. Now it ads only by one and i dont know how to make it to move as much degree as i want it to move.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Xghf/

```
var rotateObject = document.getElementById("object");
var objectRotation = 0;

var add10 = document.getElementById("add10");
var add30 = document.getElementById("add30");

add10.onclick = function(){
    rotate(0, 10);  
}
add30.onclick = function(){
    rotate(0, 30);  
}
function rotate(index, limit){
    if(objectRotation < 90 && index <= limit){
        index++;
        objectRotation++;
        rotateObject.style.transform="rotate(" + objectRotation + "deg)";
        rotateObject.style.WebkitTransform="rotate(" + objectRotation + "deg)";
        rotateObject.style.msTransform="rotate(" + objectRotation + "deg)";
        setTimeout(rotate, 50);
    }else{
    // 90 degree is the max limit for this object 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the timer by this :

```
setTimeout(function(){
        rotate(index,limit);
    }, 50);
```

nb : this won't work for all browsers

Comment: thank you :) it works, any idea how could i achive it for fully browser support ?

Comment: I would reccommend using `1000/60` as the timeout time rather than `50` to achieve a nice and smooth 60 frames per second.

Comment: Take a look here, it may give you some indications : http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/